# ¿Qué significa el valor 0\0/ en CSS?

Tags: css

Estaba añadiendo unos cambios en la hoja de estilos de un proyecto cuando me he encontrado con la siguiente regla en el CSS:

```
.elemento {
    height:0\0/
}
```

Es la primera vez que veo algo parecido y mi primer impulso ha sido borrarla porque parece que alguien con dedos gordos cometió un fallo al escribirla. Pero es un archivo bastante viejo y no sé si tiene alguna razón de ser.

He comprobado el código en diferentes navegadores, y he visto que Chrome, Firefox y Opera consideran que la regla es inválida, la muestran tachada, y la ignoran... pero Internet Explorer la interpreta como `height:0px`.

Eso me lleva a pensar que podría ser algún tipo de *hack* para versiones antiguas de Internet Explorer. Pero he buscado en Internet y no he encontrado nada (aparte de que es bastante difícil encontrar nada con esos caracteres).

¿Alguien sabe qué significa o para qué sirve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quiero aclarar que tampoco había visto eso antes, entonces mi respuesta se basa en lo que encontré en Internet:

> Es un hack para que dicho estilo se aplique únicamente a IE8 e IE9.

```
/* IE8, IE9 */
#anotherone  {color: blue\0/;} /* must go at the END of all rules */
```

Existe toda una lista de "hacks" similares para casi todos los navegadores, sin embargo no es una buena práctica actualmente.

---

La fuente principal de donde tomé esta información es este [blog post](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/) de Paul Irish.

Otras fuentes o recursos interesantes que encontré:

- http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/css_hacks.html
- http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt
- http://browserhacks.com
- http://codemug.com/html/css-hacks-for-ie6ie7ie8ie9-and-ie10

Comment: Acabé viendo un blog similar con una lista de hacks similares dependiendo de la versión de IE que se quiera tener como objetivo: http://codemug.com/html/css-hacks-for-ie6ie7ie8ie9-and-ie10/

Comment: Al menos esta vez la pregunta era un poco más difícil que otras veces, ¿no? ;)

Comment: Muy particular, además, "tantos" años jugando con css y nunca había visto esto. :o